# GridFS Nginx check if data exist

Tags: nginx, gridfs

I use (File System Based) static html files for caching, for some reasons i don like this. I want store cache files (html, images) in database.

Now it work like that:

```
if nginx can get cache:
    return cache to user
else
    proxy_pass request to backend server
```

It looks like this in my Nginx config file

```
if (-f $cache_dir_prefix/$query) {
    rewrite (.*) $query break;
}

if (!-f $cache_dir_prefix/$query) {
    proxy_pass http://lionyzer;
    break;
}
```

It's posible to do IF check with GridFS Or Amazon S3 or Mysql or anything alse?

Thanks alot

AND THE ANSWER IS

```
location /assets/ {                                                                             
    gridfs assets field=filename type=string;                                            
    mongo 127.0.0.1:27017;                                                                      
    error_page 404 = @scale;                                                                    
}                                                                                               

location @scale {                                                                               
    include fastcgi.conf;                                                                       
    fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-fpm;                                                             
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME scaleme.php;                  
}
```

Comment: One more Good answer is here https://github.com/mdirolf/nginx-gridfs/issues/10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`nginx-gridfs`](https://github.com/mdirolf/nginx-gridfs) module to serve GridFS files directly from Nginx, and then [catch a 404 for files not found](http://lserinol.blogspot.com/2009/03/speeding-up-your-nginx-server-with.html) and proxy those to the other server.